# What phrase can be used to accept an unneeded apology?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, formality

I need a word to say to the person that apologizes for something that they didn't do but feel responsible for. The word word mean: "I accept your apology, but it is not needed. (you, are entirely fine!)"

Comment: Visiting Britain, are we?

Comment: Did you mean to say _acknowledge_ in place of _accept_? To me it sounds rude to accept an apology that was not needed in the first place. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: K, I'm thinking more of something that would be like the phrase, no-thanks. In other words, "if you needed to apologize I would forgive you, but there is no need, you have done nothing wrong."

Comment: Would anyone know of a foreign word for this expression?

Answer (score 14):

You might say "Not at all!" in this situation: you're strenuously denying that there is any apology needed, which isn't actually obvious from the usage (which on the face of it looks like a non sequitur).

You could also say "No apology necessary!".  It can be tricky to pull this off, as it actually focusses attention on something that might actually just be almost a form of reflexive politeness rather than an actual apology.  As implied by my comment above this is very common in the UK, where people will apologise as a way of communicating all sorts of things, from "I'm genuinely sorry for what just happened" to "Get the f*ck out of my way" (the latter obviously being an example of **passive-aggressive behaviour**).

Possibly more "safe" is a simple "No worries" or "no problem", which just moves everyone past the awkward apologising situation as quickly as possible.

All options are best done with a smile, if you can make it look sincere.

EDIT:  if you are visiting the UK, you might want to research "British Politeness" some more, as it's a complicated subject, where not all is as it seems, although it's still easier than "Japanese Politeness" I think.

Comment: Wow, ok, I like this. I think that I was looking for a one word answer, but that seems to some degree - impossible. The story goes like this, my girlfriend steps on my foot, she says, "I'm sorry"

Comment: I just want to be able to have a just as quick and easy response that would carry a possibly deeper meaning than, "not at all"?

Comment: @TWil That's quite a confusing example though, where someone has actually done something wrong (even if you don't mind).  Also, making the example include your girlfriend instantly makes the situation much more loaded with complexity, since the relationship between two romantic partners is much more complicated than that between two people who don't know each other very well.

Comment: True... Thinking

Comment: @TWil I think either of Max Williams' suggestions of *no worries* or *no problem* might work in that case. I have used both (I'm in the US) when there was a similar minor mistake that didn't really bother me (or that did bother me, but that I didn't want the other person to feel bad about). I would also add *don't worry about it*, *it's alright*, and *it's OK*, or some combination of the above, to this category. (But note that the very similar-sounding *it's **fine*** might come across as meaning the exact opposite.)

Comment: Yes, "it's fine" seems to have lost it's own identity, here in the US. It can be taken sarcastically just as easy as it is taken actually. It just seems to me that there should be a word, native or foreign, that should contain a deeper meaning of kindness, when you are in this situation.

Comment: +1 I typically use 'No worries' or 'it's all good' in situations like this.

Comment: I think you should more clearly emphasize that "no worries" or "no problem" are the most common in situations like this

Comment: @1006a You just have to be careful about the tone of voice, really. If someone comes out with any of those responses with a flat or falling tone and no smile then you know that you've really upset them. In fact any of the phrases can downright icy and then you know you are in serious trouble!